# Environment variable affects initiation?

Tags: swift, swiftui

After I used @enviroment to get presentationMode in the beginning,
my init code seems broke,
prompting "Variable 'self.region' used before being initialized"

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExQlK.png)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
  @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
  
  init(place: Place) {
    //TOSolve: - why after using presentationmode I need underscore
    //    region = place.region
    _region = State(initialValue: place.region)
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
      
      VStack {
        HStack {
          Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()  }) {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
              .imageScale(.large)
          }
          Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        Spacer()
      }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: What line of code generates the compilation error?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson
 ,  after adding Environment(\.presentationMode) in the beginning,  my init function failed, `region = place.region` trigger error, and have to use underscore version

Comment: I think this has something to do with @Environment variables are not being guaranteed to be set when you call `init` and that the error message is caused by that but being quite misleading. Since using the _ variant is a commonly accepted solution I would've just have accepted the situation and moved on.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, thx. It's the xcode's misleading. Seems if using @Environment(\) and want to initiate @State property in init Function, I must using `_statePropertyName = State(...)` to handle errors?

Comment: You should get that error whether you use an `@Environment` variable or not. ALL `@State` variables that are not given an initial value, but are initialized in an `init()` must be initialized with an underbar and a `State(initialValue:)`. See [this](https://thinkdiff.net/swiftui-how-to-assign-state-variable-in-an-initializer-e40c33d4a3)

Comment: @Yrb   Thx, It's really helpful.